# How do I find version of Intel graphics card drivers installed?

Tags: drivers, intel, gpu, gpu-driver

My laptop came with an integrated intel GPU and with a discrete Nvidia GPU.

After the installation of ubuntu 18.04, the Nvidia server settings app was already installed and I am able to view the driver version through that.

How do I do this for the Intel driver?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can view all your video adapters with the `lspci` command

```
lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
  |    | |   |    |        \- Only VGA is not good enough,
  |    | |   |    |           because Nvidia mobile adapters
  |    | |   |    |           are shown as 3D and some AMD
  |    | |   |    |           adapters are shown as Display.
  |    | |   |    \---------  Print 3 lines after the regexp match.
  |    | |   \--------------  program for searching patterns in files
  |    | |                    (regular expressions)
  |    | \------------------  pipe used for passing the results of the
  |    |                      first command (lspci -k) to the next (grep)
  |    \--------------------  Show kernel drivers handling each device.
  \-------------------------  utility for displaying information
                              about PCI buses in the system and 
                              devices connected to them
```

The output will be something like this:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Dell HD Graphics 620
    Kernel driver in use: i915

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940MX] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Dell GM108M [GeForce 940MX]
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

As you can see, I have an Intel GPU and an Nvidia GPU. The Intel GPU is using the i915 driver and the Nvidia is using nouveau. You can check this in the `Kernel driver in use:` section of the output.

Answer (score 2):

The standard Intel driver is a built-in part of 1) the kernel, 2) the Mesa 3D graphics library. Therefore it does not have its own versioning; as long as you have the latest kernel and Mesa, you have the latest Intel driver as well.

To see your active kernel version, use `uname -r` or `dpkg -l | grep linux-image`.

To see your active Mesa version, use `glxinfo -B` or `dpkg -l | grep mesa`.

Within Xorg, interfacing with the Intel driver might be handled by the `xserver-xorg-video-intel` module. Again, use `dpkg -l` to check its version (and note that the package might not be present, in which case Xorg accesses the same Intel driver via the "modesetting" interface).